# Compiled Vala app won't run - Elementary OS

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, vala, launchpad

I have just installed Elementary OS and am learning what looks to be a pretty cool language. It's very similar to C#. I am following the tutorials step-by-step, though there are a few problems.

I'm not sure if these issues are due to my noobiness on Linux, or if I was supposed to install some things before writing Vala code - but I have installed everything the tutorial said to install.

The problem is that the Tutorial teaches us about Launchpad.net. It then later on tells us to ah push our little hello world app to Launchpad.net. Now I have created my account on Launchpad.net and I used Terminal (as per the tutorial) and when I "push" code to Launchpad.net - I don't get any feedback in the terminal - what I mean by that is, I don't know if the push was OK or if there was a problem.

Now, with the compilation of the Tutorial's sample program. WHen I compile it - again - there's no feedback like "Successfully compiled" or "Not compiled". Which I don't mind, but it turns out it did compile. It created a program, but here's the problem. I can't run it.

When I click/double-click, it won't open.

I've gone through this tutorial many times, I've done everything 100% as it says in the Tutorial but it just won't work.

So:

1. Code pushed to Launchpad does not appear in Launchpad.net, and
2. After compiling my app from the tutorial, I cannot run the app.

Can someone please help? I'm not sure what to do, or what I've done wrong.

[The tutorial](http://elementaryos.org/docs/code/hello-world)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did a chmod +x ./programname on the file didn't you?  You won't be able to run it unless uou set it as executable.  You can also do this with a file manager, right clicking and choosing properties.

Comment: Ooh I know chmod! Thanks, it didn't even occur to me. I'm going to do that now.

Comment: Cool... Thanks for giving me my first 25 reps :)

Need to add Vala as a fave langauge, I'd forgotten all about Vala!

Comment: No prob :) Yeah Vala looks real promising, i can't wait to make some real stuff with it!